# C# SQL statement doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

When I execute the command to insert the values of a data table into a SQL Server database I get an error.

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

My code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) // i = 1 instead of 0 because of the header row
{
    wipSql = "INSERT INTO tblWIP ([FSR Number], [Customer Name], REGN_NM, SUBREGN_NM, [EMP/SUPPLIER Name], [INVTY DATE], " +
             "[COST CATEGORY], [PL&M AMOUNT], [LABOR AMOUNT], [T&L PERDIEM], [MEMO COST], [EDI SEQ#], [INVOICE NUMBER], [Grand Total], Age, Business) " + 
             "VALUES ('"
                      + dt.Rows[i]["FSR Number"].ToString().Trim() + "', '"
                      + dt.Rows[i]["Customer Name"].ToString().Trim() + "', '"
                      + dt.Rows[i]["REGN_NM"].ToString().Trim() + "', '"
                      + dt.Rows[i]["SUBREGN_NM"].ToString().Trim() + "', '"
                      + dt.Rows[i]["EMP/SUPPlier Name"].ToString().Trim() + "', '"
                      + dt.Rows[i]["INVTY DATE"].ToString().Trim() + "', '"
                      + dt.Rows[i]["COST CATEGORY"].ToString().Trim() + "', "
                      + dt.Rows[i]["PL&M AMOUNT"].ToString().Trim() + ", "
                      + dt.Rows[i]["LABOR AMOUNT"].ToString().Trim() + ", "
                      + dt.Rows[i]["T&L PERDIEM"].ToString().Trim() + ", "
                      + dt.Rows[i]["MEMO COST"].ToString().Trim() + ", '"
                      + dt.Rows[i]["EDI SEQ#"].ToString().Trim() + "', '"
                      + dt.Rows[i]["INVOICE NUMBER"].ToString().Trim() + "', "
                      + dt.Rows[i]["Grand Total"].ToString().Trim() + ", "
                      + dt.Rows[i]["Age"].ToString().Trim() + ", '"
                      + dt.Rows[i]["Business"].ToString().Trim() + "')";

    SqlCommand cmdWIP = new SqlCommand(wipSql, localConnection);
    cmdWIP.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: did you try to print `wipSql` and see the resultant output query? a recommended way would be to use sql parameters and not do string appending to create a sql statement

Comment: based on your error i feel that you are missing some quotes.

Comment: +1 for ughai's recommendation for using parameters.  You're leaving yourself wide open for errors if a customer's name contains quote (eg. "O'Connor"), and for SQL injection attacks.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you are missing some quotes in + dt.Rows[i]["INVOICE NUMBER"].ToString().Trim() + "', " and afterwards, it should be like "', '"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ,

```
string wipSql = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) // i = 1 instead of 0 because of the header row
        {
            wipSql = "INSERT INTO tblWIP ([FSR Number], [Customer Name], REGN_NM, SUBREGN_NM, [EMP/SUPPLIER Name], [INVTY DATE], [COST CATEGORY], [PL&M AMOUNT], [LABOR AMOUNT], [T&L PERDIEM], [MEMO COST], [EDI SEQ#], [INVOICE NUMBER], [Grand Total],  Age, Business) VALUES(@FSRNumber, @CustomerName, @REGN_NM, @SUBREGN_NM, @SupplierName, @InventoryDate, @CostCategory, @PLMAmount, @LaborAmount, @TLPerdiem, @MemoCost, @Ediseq, @InvoiceNumber, @GrandTotal, @Age, @Business)";

            SqlCommand cmdWIP = new SqlCommand(wipSql, localConnection);
            cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FSRNumber", dt.Rows[i]["FSR Number"].ToString().Trim());
            cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", dt.Rows[i]["Customer Name"].ToString().Trim());
            cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REGN_NM", dt.Rows[i]["REGN_NM"].ToString().Trim());
            cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SUBREGN_NM", dt.Rows[i]["SUBREGN_NM"].ToString().Trim());
            cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierName", dt.Rows[i]["EMP/SUPPlier Name"].ToString().Trim());
            cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InventoryDate", dt.Rows[i]["INVTY DATE"].ToString().Trim());
            cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CostCategory", dt.Rows[i]["COST CATEGORY"].ToString().Trim());
            cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PLMAmount", dt.Rows[i]["PL&M AMOUNT"].ToString().Trim());
            cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LaborAmount", dt.Rows[i]["LABOR AMOUNT"].ToString().Trim());
            cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TLPerdiem", dt.Rows[i]["T&L PERDIEM"].ToString().Trim());
            cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemoCost", dt.Rows[i]["MEMO COST"].ToString().Trim());
            cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ediseq", dt.Rows[i]["EDI SEQ#"].ToString().Trim());
            cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceNumber", dt.Rows[i]["INVOICE NUMBER"].ToString().Trim());
            cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GrandTotal", dt.Rows[i]["Grand Total"].ToString().Trim());
            cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", dt.Rows[i]["Age"].ToString().Trim());
            cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Business", dt.Rows[i]["Business"].ToString().Trim());


            cmdWIP.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Start using query  parameters and problems like this will be avoided and you will be protected from sql injection. Also start using `@` this give you the possibility to write string on multiple lines.

```
wipSql = @"INSERT INTO 
            tblWIP ([FSR Number], [Customer Name], REGN_NM, SUBREGN_NM, [EMP/SUPPLIER Name], [INVTY DATE], [COST CATEGORY], [PL&M AMOUNT], [LABOR AMOUNT], [T&L PERDIEM], [MEMO COST], [EDI SEQ#], [INVOICE NUMBER], [Grand Total], Age, Business) 
           VALUES
               (@Number, @Name, @Regn_NM, .... and so on )";

//after that here
SqlCommand cmdWIP = new SqlCommand(wipSql, localConnection);
cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Number, dt.Rows[i]["FSR Number"].ToString().Trim());
cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Name, dt.Rows[i]["Customer Name"].ToString().Trim());
cmdWIP.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Regn_NM, dt.Rows[i]["REGN_NM"].ToString().Trim());
//and so on for other parameters
```

Comment: Recommended reading: [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection#Example_2)